# PDO Replicating rows in different servers General Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I am trying to "move" selected rows from 1 table to another in different databases.

It in theory works (but if anyone wants to give any opinions please do, I am very new to PDO. I however keep getting a "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error" error.

Any advice?

```
  private function broken() {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `calls` WHERE `calls`.`status`=0 AND `calls`.`stage` < 4 AND `calls`.`answer` < (NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)";
        $query = $this->staging->query($sql);
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            // Insert in production database:
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `ivr_incomplete` (`id`,`sip_id`,`extension`,`caller_id`,`stage`,`status`,`survey_id`,`start`,`answer`,`hangup`,`end`) VALUES (:id, :sip_id, :extension, :caller_id, :stage, :status, :survey_id, :start, :answer, :hangup, :end)";
            $query = $this->production->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute($row);

            // Delete from staging:
            $sql = "DELETE FROM `calls` WHERE `id`='".$row['id']."'";
            $this->staging->query($sql);

        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $this->informer("FATAL", "Unable to process broken IVR surveys. Error: ".$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points:

1. You are preparing the `INSERT` on every iteration, which sort of eliminates half of the point of using a prepared statement - all you are using it for is escaping. One of the points of prepared statements is that the query is only parsed once, so if you need to execute the same query repeatedly with different values, calling `prepare()` once and then simply calling `execute()` with the different data sets can significantly boost performance.
2. <strike>This whole thing could be accomplished in 2 queries:</strike> <sup>Removed due to use of two separate DB connections</sup>

**EDIT**

Try this code:

You will likely need to adjust the error handling to meet your needs, particularly around how it is handled if there is an error with an `INSERT`, since I doubt you would want to break the whole operation and leave the rows that have been successfully processed in the source table.

```
private function broken() {

    try {

        // Fetch records to move
        $sql = "
          SELECT *
          FROM `calls`
          WHERE `status` = 0
            AND `stage` < 4
            AND `answer` < (NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
        ";
        $query = $this->staging->query($sql);
        if (!$query) {
            $errorInfo = $this->staging->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("MySQL error at SELECT: $errorInfo[1] ($errorInfo[0]): $errorInfo[2]");
        }

        // Prepare the INSERT statement
        $sql = "
          INSERT INTO `ivr_incomplete`
            (`id`,`sip_id`,`extension`,`caller_id`,`stage`,`status`,`survey_id`,`start`,`answer`,`hangup`,`end`)
          VALUES
            (:id, :sip_id, :extension, :caller_id, :stage, :status, :survey_id, :start, :answer, :hangup, :end)
        ";
        if (!$stmt = $this->production->prepare($sql)) {
            $errorInfo = $this->production->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("MySQL error at prepare INSERT: $errorInfo[1] ($errorInfo[0]): $errorInfo[2]");
        }

        // A list of the row IDs we are working with
        $rowIds = array();

        // Loop the results and insert them
        for ($i = 1; $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $i++) {

            if (!$stmt->execute($row)) {
                $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
                throw new Exception("MySQL error at INSERT row $i (id: {$row['id']}): $errorInfo[1] ($errorInfo[0]): $errorInfo[2]");
            }

            $rowIds[] = (int) $row['id'];

        }

        // Delete from staging:
        if ($rowIds) {

            $sql = "
              DELETE FROM `calls`
              WHERE `id` IN (".implode(', ', $rowIds).")
            ";
            if (!$this->staging->query($sql)) {
                $errorInfo = $this->staging->errorInfo();
                throw new Exception("MySQL error at DELETE: $errorInfo[1] ($errorInfo[0]): $errorInfo[2]");
            }

        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        $this->informer("FATAL", "Unable to process broken IVR surveys (PDO). Error: ".$e->getMessage());

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $this->informer("FATAL", "Unable to process broken IVR surveys (MySQL). Error: ".$e->getMessage());

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @DaveRandom. The problem is that I am using 2 seperate database connections. The tables does not reside on the same server, hence why I am first selecting the rows then passing them to a different table

Comment: @MauritzSwanepoel Oh yeh, sorry, I totally missed that. But the point about calling `prepare()` once outside the loop still stands. It will potentially give a significant performance boost. To be honest SQLSTATE codes aren't that useful - we could do with the string error from MySQL (element `2` of the array returned by `PDO::errorInfo()`/`PDOStatement::errorInfo()`)

Comment: Hey @DaveRandom, thank you for your code above, I like the way you think :) Out of curiousity, would transactions not have worked better or be a solution as well? I am literally dying to use transactions in a app. Could I do a transaction that if 1 fails nothing continues?

Comment: @MauritzSwanepoel I suppose you *could* but to be brutally honest I don't really see the point here. If you were working with two tables in the same DB, then transactions would be a good solution using the two queries I suggested originally. But here there isn't much point because you are bringing the working data into PHP and only deleting records based on the data you select at the beginning, so there is no danger of data become corrupted because the table is modified while you are working - which is the main thing transactions are there to avoid.

Comment: agreed! Thanks for the answer, approving :)